# How can I use multiple shipping values in satchmo?

Tags: django, satchmo, django-apps

There's already some shipping modules such as FEDEX, Flat Rate, Per pieced and UPS but how can I let the user choose its preferred shipping method and/or price?

For those who don't know, [Satchmo](http://www.satchmoproject.com/) is a django app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

arrg I'm dumb.

Just found my answer by going through the shipping folder again and by reading the source code.

1. seems like I have to add the "satchmo.shipping.modules.tiered" app in my INSTALLED_APPS list.
2. run "python manage.py syncdb" to add the appropriate models in the database
3. Add some custom carriers in the Carriers table using the admin interface